# loop over with_subelements ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Hi have following variable:

```
couchbase:
 - name: incre1
   ipaddress:
    - 10.16.9.177
    - 10.16.9.178
   buckets:
    - AA1
    - aa1
```

And my plabook have following:

```
 - debug:
    msg: "Running backup as {{CBBACKUPMGR}} backup -r {{ item.1 }} --cluster couchbase://{{ item.0.ipaddress }}"
   register: example
   with_subelements:
     - "{{ couchbase }}"
     -  buckets
```

And i want to iterate over ipaddress and then with buckets, so basically i want to see:

```
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r AA1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.177
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r aa1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.177
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r AA1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.178
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r aa1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.178
```

However, when running the playbook i'm seeing as following:

```
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r AA1 --cluster couchbase://[u'10.16.9.177', u'10.16.9.178']
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r aa1 --cluster couchbase://[u'10.16.9.177', u'10.16.9.178']
```

Comment: What is the question? Everything works like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats not what `with_subelements` does. If you use this "debug" loop to print the {{ item }}, you will see that on each iteration, it creates a list of:

1. the parent element from the `couchbase` list that holds the subelement you specified, WITHOUT the hash of that subelement and
2. the value of the subelement of that iteration.

here is the output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ipaddress": [
                "10.16.9.177", 
                "10.16.9.178"
            ], 
            "name": "incre1"
        }, 
        "AA1"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ipaddress": [
                "10.16.9.177", 
                "10.16.9.178"
            ], 
            "name": "incre1"
        }, 
        "aa1"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP
```

As you clarified, your intention is to generate all possible combinations between `ipaddress` and `buckets`.

to achieve this, try this task:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "Running backup as {{CBBACKUPMGR}} backup -r {{ item[0] }} --cluster couchbase://{{ item[1] }}"
    register: example
    with_items:
      - "{{ lookup('nested', couchbase[0].ipaddress, couchbase[0].buckets) }}"
```

This assumes you will have the `couchbase` list variable with only one element, just as it is in your example.

result:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r 10.16.9.177 --cluster couchbase://AA1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r 10.16.9.177 --cluster couchbase://aa1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r 10.16.9.178 --cluster couchbase://AA1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r 10.16.9.178 --cluster couchbase://aa1"
}

PLAY RECAP
```

hope it helps.

Comment: that seems to be working as described by you. thanks a lot.
Is there any option that i can put condition on loop. Let's say if first execution is successful, then skip the next. For example:
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r AA1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.177
Running backup as /opt/ouchbase backup -r aa1 --cluster couchbase://10.16.9.177

skip rest of 178. Basically skipping the rest elements of parent loop i.e. couchbase[0].ipaddress

Comment: I really am not sure how you can do this, but should be a way. perhaps with `register` and `until` clause? i know how to do the opposite, exit a loop with `failed_when` clause but consider it a succesful run, not sure :(

Comment: I have tried following:
 `    - name: run the db backup
       shell: "{{CBBACKUPMGR}} backup -a {{ARCHIVE}} -r {{ item.1 }}_{{base_date.stdout}} --cluster couchbase://{{ item.0 }} --username {{USERNAME}} --password {{PASSWORD}}"
       register: backup_out
       with_items:
         - "{{ lookup('nested', couchbase[0].ipaddress, couchbase[0].buckets) }}"
       until: backup_out.rc == 0`
But it keep continuing.  Loop doesn't break

Comment: i see, it was a longshot :( i am not sure how you can implement a break out of the loop in case of successful run. maybe you will get lucky finding something from google or SO's search?